# Suggestions for starting a entity framework code first project from scratch

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a project from scratch. I'll be using asp .net mvc4 (with asp net web api), and entity framework 5 for data access (all the latest technologies)

Since it's a fresh start, I was thinking on centering my design on my model rather than creating the database first and then creating the EF model, so I though I'd go with a code first approach.

The problem with code first (as far as I see) is that you lose all the scaffolding that EF does for you on a model first scenario (design support, easily generating and maintaining entity relationships 1-1, 1-*, *-*, etc)
The question is : What tools or templates or snippets or whatever can I use to make my life easier when designing my model?. I want this process to be as painless as possible, since it involves a lot of repetition (FK relationships, for example, are the same always)
Should I use DbContext or something else? Is there some kind of way to start code first but at the same time maintain an edmx model, or those are mutually exclusive?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want to use Model First. Code First is for those who *don't want* to mess with the model designer.

Comment: that's fine, I don't <need> to mess with the model designer, actually, I prefer to have as much control as possible on what I have, and centre on my model. However, I anyway need to set everything up : relationships between classes, constraints, etc, that will finally end up in a generated database. What I want to know is what tools can I use to help scaffold repetitive tasks

Comment: Relationships are defined in the classes that you build, by collection properties and foreign key properties, for example. You use DataAnnotations or Fluent Configuration to define various constraints and hints for the database generation. As for scaffolding repetitive tasks, that's really outside the scope of EF anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great thing about EF Code First is that you don't need any scaffolding. You don't need an EDMX model, you don't even need to specify the exact nature of relationships, it's all based on conventions.  For example your classes must have a property called Id, which will be taken to be the Primary Key of the table.  All string based fields are generated as `nvarchar(MAX)`.  Of course some conventions might not be what you want and Code First supports this through pluggable conventions (you can remove most conventions and create your own)

You should do some of the basic tutorials to get an idea of how the Code First flow works as it's an entirely different proposition to the Db First approach.

Comment: `string` fields are actually generated as `nvarchar(MAX)`, unless you specify a max string length. Otherwise, exactly correct! +1 in anticipation of that minor error being fixed :)

Comment: Lol, thanks, I think it might then be NHibernate that generates them as 255 by default.

Comment: thanks Jaimal! can you point me out to some good EF5 code first tutorials?? (apart from msdn)

Comment: EF5 Code First is pretty new, you might better of looking at EF4 Code First tutorials for now (although there will be differences). I used this one from Scott Gu back when EF Code First was released http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx